# Prepare statement with chpasswd

Tags: mysql

---  I have written this below procedure but getting syntax error in
prepare statement  ----

DELIMITER $$

drop procedure if exists test;

CREATE PROCEDURE test()
BEGIN

```
DECLARE min_counter INT ;
DECLARE max_counter INT ; 
DECLARE usr varchar(20);
DECLARE pwd varchar(20);
DECLARE var1 varchar(100);


select id into min_counter from ftp order by id limit 0,1;

select id into max_counter  from ftp order by id desc limit 0,1;

WHILE min_counter <= max_counter do
   select usr1 into usr from ftp where id = min_counter; 
   select new_passwd into pwd from ftp where id = min_counter; 

    set @stm = "\! echo "$usr":$pwd" | chpasswd";
    prepare stmt from @stm;
    execute stmt;
    deallocate prepare stmt;
    SET min_counter  =  min_counter + 1 ;
    END WHILE;
```

END$$

DELIMITER ;

Comment: You need to tell MySql you are using 'variables' in your queries. Prefix the names with the '@' symbol. e.g: `select id into @min_counter ...`. Maybe interesting? https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-select-into-variable/ The internet search I used was: "mysql select into variables"

Comment: I ma getting sysntax error in this line :   set @stm = "\! echo "$usr":$pwd" | chpasswd";

Comment: Escape the nested double qoutes. see  set @stm = "\! echo \"$usr\":$pwd\" | chpasswd";  I have tested it.

Comment: Thanks but i am still getting syntax error during compilation but if we add concat like this set @stm = concat('"\! echo \"$usr\":$pwd\" | chpasswd"') then not geeting error during compilation but while running the procedure getting the following syntax error: ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '"! echo "$usr":$pwd" | chpasswd"' at line 1

Comment: Tell us what you are trying to do with 1) The @stm variable? is it a command to be used elsewhere?  2) What are you going to use the out from the SQL query for?

Comment: 1. I am trying to change the passwd by using this command : execute stmt ;this query is running fine from sql if i put static value but when i am trying to run this command inside procedure i am getting syntax error which i mentioned earlier. Pls help.

Comment: Update your question with all the details of what you are trying to do. Include the steps that you used to successfully change it manually. I want you do this so that you you can compare what the individual steps that you are trying to do.

Comment: I am able to change the password  when i am giving static value like this  :   \! echo "unix_cloud:09ucs_#$" | chpasswd; But as i described earlier when i am trying this through stored procedure  i am getting syntax error. Can you please assist on this.